# Unable to create IIS site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I am creating a web application and selecting to create a new IIS site and new application pool in IIS, it does not create both. 
However web application gets created, I was also able to create site collection under it but when I am trying to open a site collection it says "page can not be displayed". Not sure what is going wrong.
Using sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the site collection on the root site yet?

for example :

you have create site collection at : http://yourspserver.example/sites/blabla

but you have not create site collection at : http://yourspserver.example/

Comment: I have Not created a site collection on root yet...  created http://yourspserver.example/sites/blabla 
do i have to create a root site to show site in IIS ?

Comment: I have just created http://yourspserver.example/ and it is still the same, page can not be displayed

Comment: Not able to see IIS site in IIS manager

Comment: When you create the web application, did you wait until the message web application is created successfully? i'm afraid its timeout on the process, because the web server should be on IIS manager

Comment: actually there also it says page can not be displayed at the end but creates the webapp

Comment: found that the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application was in 'Stopping' state.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288605(v=office.12).aspx :

stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype SPWebservice
iisreset
stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype SPWebservice
iisreset

Post the above step the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application was in 'Started' state.
Tried to check IIS & noticed all the Web Applications being present.

Comment: i think you should post an answer if that works for you, so if others have same problem, they wont confuse whether this question is already solved or not

Comment: webapplication service had issues.. restarting that solved it

Answer (score 1):

when you says its created, did you see the webapplication in IIS or From Central Admin > Manager WebApplication?

did you try to create the webapplication using the Powershell?
here is technet code for this, try this 
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Create-SharePoint-Web-742a8fb9.

also check this blog for the time out issue, you need to make changes to defaulapp pool.

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Error-while-Creating-Web-Application-through-Central-Administration

Comment: I see from central admin.. In iis nothing appears.. and that is the issue

Comment: delete this webapp from central admin, then reset IIS. after that try to create webApp using the powershell script.

Comment: I dont understand why should I do that when It is happening for all the webapps and client does not use powershell, I have to use the console itself and get it fixed to do that

Comment: your end user having the ability to create a webapplication? if a user has ability to create a webapplication then he definitely has access to sharepoint server, because without farm admin you cannot create web application. as an Admin of the farm, you must use the console becuase GUI is not giving you some control....why i am asking for powershell becuase may be your IE timeout, so just avoiding that.............

Comment: Not the users.. they have a dev team and its a dev server.. its a shared project.. anyways I will try the powershell and update you. :)

Comment: found that the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application was in 'Stopping' state.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288605(v=office.12).aspx :

stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype SPWebservice
iisreset
stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype SPWebservice
iisreset

Post the above step the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application was in 'Started' state.
Tried to check IIS & noticed all the Web Applications being present.